# prevent authors from merging their own code on github

Tags: git, security, github

In order to gain some compliance certification we need to ensure that anyone putting code into master was not an author on that code, to prevent someone from single-handedly inserting malicious code.

The approach I'm thinking of is to use master branch protection with a status check. We'll have an intermediary branch that we merge work onto, and we can check those commits to ensure that they were not merged by the original author. Then we apply a 'green' status to that commit, and only green commits can go into master.

Perhaps there is a better approach? I haven't been able to find anything, but if I'm overlooking a feature or common practice for this problem I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn on [Protected Branch](https://help.github.com/articles/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/)
2. Add one of many systems such as [reviewable.io](http://reviewable.io) as a CI System.
3. [Customize what makes a reviewable review complete](https://github.com/Reviewable/Reviewable/wiki/FAQ#can-i-customize-what-makes-a-review-complete) and require a separate reviewer (and any other of your requirements.
4. Set GitHub to [require the CI System to Pass to merge](https://help.github.com/articles/about-required-status-checks/) to the protected branch.

Comment: Thx Travis, that is similar to what I was trying but my problem is that relying on 'required status checks' (your step 4) can be easily bypassed by manually posting your desired status to the commit.

Comment: This should only be true if everyone on your project is an owner.  If they are a contributor and you follow all the steps in the answer, they currently cannot bypass the protection.

Comment: Hmm I'll have to test that. I asked github specificially and they said 'Nothing is preventing them -- that's the point of the API: it allows you to perform some actions if you have the right permissions, just like the UI. If a user have push access to a repository -- then they can create statuses. Users with just pull access can't create statuses.'